# Interchanging Expectation and Derivative

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, derivatives, lebesgue-integral, expectation

Suppose I have a random function, $f(x)(\omega)$.  And that for fixed $\omega$, we have the derivative $g(x)(\omega)=\frac{d}{dx}f(x)(\omega)$.  For a fixed $x$, I can find the expectation $E(f(x))$.  Suppose I want to find the derivative of this expectation with respect to $x$, i.e., $\frac{d}{dx}E(f(x))$?  When can I say that $$\frac{d}{dx}E(f(x))=E(g(x))?$$  Does it suffice to assume that $$E(g(x))<\infty?$$ Or can I assume less or do I need to assume more? Of course, I could use dominated convergence if I had an appropriate function.  But lets assume I don't actually know what $f$ is so I can't find a specific function to use dominated convergence with.

Comment: Minor comment: Instead of "for set $\omega$...For a set $x$..." I think you mean "for outcome $\omega$...For a real number $x$..."

Comment: @Michael I think the OP meant "set" as in "fixed," not as in a set of numbers or something like that.

Comment: @kccu : I did not interpret it that way, your interpretation makes more sense.  I was thinking "sets" because probabilistic events are just sets, while outcomes are elements of sets.

Comment: I Googled to find the following notes, among many:  https://www.math.ntnu.no/~hek/Optimering2012/TheoremA13.pdf

Comment: @Michael Yes I meant fixed and have corrected

Comment: @Michael I found the same link previous to my posting.  But as I said what if you can't find such a function to use as your "dominator"?  Does my assumption of integrability of g(x) work?  Is that too much?

Answer (score 1):

What about this (counter) example: Let $Z$ be a random variable that is never $0$, and that has PDF: 
$$ f_Z(z) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-|z|} \quad \forall z \in \mathbb{R} $$
In particular, $|Z|$ is a positive and exponentially distributed random variable with rate $\lambda =1$. Define: 
$$ r(x)  = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
0  &\mbox{ if $|x| \leq 1/|Z|$} \\
xe^{1/|x|} & \mbox{ if $|x|> 1/|Z|$} 
\end{array}
\right.$$
Then for all realizations of $Z$ we have $r(0)=r'(0)=0$, and so $E[r(0)]=E[r'(0)]=0$.  However, for all $x\neq 0$ we have
$$ E[r(x)] = xe^{1/|x|}P[|Z|>1/|x|] = xe^{1/|x|}e^{-1/|x|} = x $$
Since $E[r(0)]=0$, it follows that $E[r(x)]=x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus:
$$ \frac{d}{dx} E[r(x)] = 1   \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R} $$ 
In particular, 
$$\frac{d}{dx} E[r(x)]|_{x=0} = 1 \neq 0 = E[r'(0)] $$